# Does the expectation maximization algorithm apply to this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, conditional-expectation, expectation-maximization

I have a sample of variables $x_i$, where each one is a function of known variables $y_i$ and $b_i$, and of an unknown variable $\alpha_i$.

$$x_i=y_ib_i-y_i^{\alpha_i}$$

The density function of $x_i$ has unknown parameters $\mu_x,\sigma_x$.  However, it can be shown that these unknown parameters are a function of the known parameters $\mu_y,\sigma_y$ of the density function of $y_i$, *as well as* an unknown parameter $\beta$.  In particular:

$$\sigma_x=\sigma_y\sqrt{1+\beta}$$
$$\mu_x=\mu_y(1-\beta)$$

Is it possible to solve for the unknown parameters $\alpha_i$ and $\beta$ using the expectation-maximization algorithm, or something along those lines?  Any guidance in general about how I might solve for the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta$ would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is \beta related to \alpha_i? If not then how does one use it in the estimation equations? Why not use MLE on X to estimate paramaters? Why use EM? Is your likelihood difficult to optimize? A lot is missing. Can you work out the calculation for $\mu_x=E[X]$ that will add some more clarity to the question

Comment: @RohitArora For more background on the motivation for this question, please see my other question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167695/how-to-estimate-parameters-for-each-observation-using-mle