# How to estimate parameters for each observation using MLE

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

Given a sample of variables $x_i$, which are each a function of the known variables $y_i,b_i$ and an unknown parameter $\alpha_i$

$$x_i=y_ib_i-y_i^{\alpha_i}$$

I thought I might solve for the unknown $\alpha_i$ using MLE.  However, the first order conditions aren't helping me out too much.  For eg., suppose the $x_i$ are lognormally disrtibuted.  Then the log likelihood function is:

$$\ln(l)=-\frac{n}{2}\ln(2\pi)-n\ln(\sigma_x)-\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x_i)-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(\ln(x_i)-\mu_x)^2}{2\sigma_x^2}$$

The F.O.Cs for a maximum, $\frac{\partial\ln(l)}{\partial \alpha_i}=0$, yield the following equation for each $i$:

$$\frac{\partial\ln(l)}{\partial \alpha_i}=\frac{\partial\ln(l)}{\partial \ln(x_i)}\frac{\partial \ln(x_i)}{\partial \alpha_i}=\left(-1-\frac{\ln(x_i)-\mu_x}{\sigma_x^2} \right)\frac{\partial \ln(x_i)}{\partial \alpha_i}=0$$

$$\mu_x-\sigma_x^2=\ln(x_i)$$

I could then solve this for the $\alpha_i$ but I stop here because this equation would mean that all of the $x_i$ have the same value, which is certainly not true.  Have I made a mistake somewhere or is MLE simply an inappropriate approach to solving for the unkown $\alpha_i$?  Suggestions of other approaches to solving for the $\alpha_i$ (EM algorithm?  HMM?) are welcome.

Comment: $$\alpha _i = \frac{{\ln \left( {{y_i}{b_i} - {e^{{\mu _x} - \sigma _x^2}}} \right)}}{{\ln \left( {{y_i}} \right)}}$$. $\alpha_i$ depends on $y_i$ There is a different value for each $\alpha_i$, so I don't understand what you mean when you say all $x_i$ will have the same value

Comment: What is the probability model here? You have given a deterministic formula for $x_i$; where is the random component? Normal errors?

Comment: @Placidia Variables $y_i,b_i$ are independent random variables with their own density functions.

Comment: @RohitArora The parameters $\mu_x,\sigma_x$ are of the density function $f(x_i;\mu_x,\sigma_x)$ (which in the example above is a lognormal density function).  Thus $\mu_x,\sigma_x$ are the same for all observations $x_i$.  Thus $\mu_x-\sigma_x^2$ is constant for all $i$.  Thus the F.O.C.s indicate that $\ln(x_i)$ must be constant for all $i$.  Do you agree?